# Show that a language is not regular by Pumping Lemma

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-languages, pumping-lemma

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prove that a language is not regular?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-regular)

Show that $L_2=\{a^nb^k|n\not= k-1\}$ is not regular by Pumping Lemma.

Comment: Or actually showing by any method is fine.

Comment: Welcome! Please check [our reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-regular). If you can't get any of the approaches to work, please include your attempts here and flag for reopening.